# Взаимное обтекание 2 колонок

Tags: вёрстка, html, css

Есть простая 2-колоночная вёрстка блока; ширина статичная, float: left|right; в одной - мозаика картинок, в другой - текст; но, разность из высоты различна: может быть больше как картинок, так и текста. Можно ли в рамках CSS заставить одну колонку обтекать другую, если та это позволяет?

Comment: В том виде, как вы написали - думаю нет.

В любом случае потребуется либо размещение одного блока "внутри другого", либо какая-то многокомпонентная верстка (когда данные разбиты на много блоков (не обязательно очевидно для пользователя)) и JS для управления этим всем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В голову приходит вариант использования одинаковых float'ов ( left или right) для обеих колонок и тогда обтекание будет, но т.к. у Вас высота заранее не известна, то может быть проверять на JS высоту и делать float в ту сторону где меньше контента. (Если мало картинок то left, много текста - right ).